# get Event Data from paypal webhooks

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm new to paypal api. What I'm trying is to be notified when a user makes a purchase using the webhooks api.

In Webhooks simulator I introduced the URL where paypal could inform me about a sale , and I simulated a  "Payment sale completed". The page at that URL is called, and paypal says that "Event Data Sent" and there is a JSON object that is sent. Everything is great, but how do I get that json object in PHP ? Is it sent via POST?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figure it out. all you have to do is :

```
$bodyReceived = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts as well.

Comment: Years have passed but I just wanted to say thank you, you're a life saver :D